# Animate using custom CSS on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, animation

I have added my slide-in-from-left animation definition to wordpress's custom css, and now I want it to start upon html start/show/created event (I am coming from Android Java... Not a big HTML expert myself). Can I do that easily, without a plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the site_admin, in the left navigation bar, click plugins->editor, when you can see all your css and php files for your wordpress theme.